# Creating a running total

Tags: c#

This is a simple calculator. It performs calculations. However, every time it calculates I want to save that total and add it to a running total. Creating a running total is where I am having my issue. Can someone please help me? This is suppose to be in memento format. So when I undo a stack is removed or a total from a previous calculation. I am struggling with that.

```
class Calculator
{
    public Stack<double> result= new Stack<double>();
    double total;

    public void Add(double a, double b)
    {
        total = a + b;
        Console.WriteLine("Sum:{0}", total);
        result.Push(total);
    }
    public void Sub(double a, double b)
    {
        total = a - b;
        Console.WriteLine("Difference:{0}", total);
        result.Push(total);
    }
    public void Mul(double a, double b)
    {
        total = a * b;
        Console.WriteLine("Product:{0} ", total);
        result.Push(total);
    }
    public void Div(double a, double b)
    {
        if (b!=0)
        {
            total = a / b;
            Console.WriteLine("Quotient:{0}", total);
            result.Push(total);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Cannot divide by 0");
        }
    }

    double GetTotal()
    {
        return total;

    }
    void Undo()
    {
        if (result.Count==0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("UNDO IS NOT AVAILABLE");
        }
        result.Pop();
        total = result.Pop();
        Console.WriteLine("Running total:{0}", total);
    }
    void clear()
    {
        while (result.Count !=0)
            result.Pop();
        total = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Running total:{0}", total);
    }
    static int Main()
    {
        Calculator cal=new Calculator();
        string line="";
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter (Clear, Undo, Exit, Expression):");

            if (line.ToLower() == "exit")
                break;
            else if (line.ToLower() == "undo")
                cal.Undo();
            else if (line.ToLower() == "clear")
                cal.clear();
            else
            {
                double a, b;



                Console.WriteLine("Write the first number");
                double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a);

                Console.WriteLine("Write the second number");
                double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out b);

                Console.WriteLine("Write the operand (+, -, /, *)");
                char.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out char c);

                Console.WriteLine("Total:{0}", cal.total);

                if (c == '+')
                    cal.Add(a, b);
                if (c == '-')
                    cal.Sub(a, b);
                if (c == '*')
                    cal.Mul(a, b);
                if (c == '/')
                    cal.Div(a, b);
            }
        }
        return 0;
```

Comment: Seems like you just need to modify the total during your `Push()` and `Pop()` operations.

Comment: It seems like you're overwriting total on each operation but a running total would be the total of all operations; correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, initialize your `total`.

```
double total = 0;
```

Then, instead of simply assigning to `total`, do `total +=`
Also, you'd want to do the `push` before you add the new result to running total.

```
public void Add(double a, double b)
{
    var temp = a + b;
    Console.WriteLine("Sum:{0}", temp);
    result.Push(temp);
    total += temp;
}
```

Follow the same idea for other operations like division and multiplication.

### EDIT:

Reading your question again, I'm not clear if you want to store each individual result in the stack, or if you want to store each progressive total. The above example is to store the result of each individual operation. If you want to simply store each new total in the stack:

```
public void Add(double a, double b)
{
    total += a + b;
    Console.WriteLine("Sum:{0}", total);
    result.Push(total);
}
```

Comment: It works but how come when I undo it does not take away the previous calculation from the running total?

Comment: You seem to do two `Pop()` operations inside `Undo()` which I don' think is what you want?